# using substring to add word to string

Tags: php, position, substring

Not sure if the title for this is correct but here's my problem:
I have a table that hold image's url like so:

```
img/folder/imagename.jpg
```

Now I've created a thumbnail for each image in each folder, so if I want to display them I do a loop in my table and return all the url's but I need to add the word "thumbs" after "folder/" and before the "imagename.jpg"...Now because obviously the "folder" and "imagename" names differ in length then I can't do a count..the only thing I can figure is to look up that last "/" character and insert there and add on the "imagename.jpg" after it so end result would look like:

```
img/folder/thumbs/imagename.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace the path with a "deeper" path:

```
$path = str_replace('img/folder/', 'img/folder/thumbs/', $path);
```

There are lots of other ways to do this, but IMHO this one is perfectly clear on what it does. *Theoretically* it won't work universally (if your path contains multiple occurreces of `img/folder/` for some reason), but let's just not go there.

Answer (score 1):

you can also

```
$pathparts =  explode("/",$path);
```

and then use $pathparts array to construct your path again. You would use it in cases you want to have more control over manipulating paths, but in heavy loads it's not very efficient.

```
echo $pathparts[0]."/".$pathparts[1]."/thumbs/".$pathparts[2];
```

//adition
And why not to update your database and script only save imagename.jpg
and then in the beginning of calling script define

```
define("IMGPATH", "img/folder/");
define("THUMBPATH", "img/folder/thumbs/");
```

and then call it

```
 <?= IMGPATH."imagename.jpg" ?>
<?= THUMBPATH."imagename.jpg" ?>
```